# WebStorm saves files on edit

Tags: ide, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

My JetBrains WebStorm gone crazy and started to save files right after I type the character. Autosave settings are disabled (I like to save files manually). Any ideas why this could happen or how to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

WebStorm doesn't normally auto-save files on each key pressing. If it only happens while debugging your app, check if *Live Edit* (that is active during debug session) is enabled in ***Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | Live Edit*** - it auto-saves files to provide live reload. Some other plugins can also be responsible for auto-saving - for example, third-party [SonarLint](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7973-sonarlint) and [ESLint](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7494-eslint) plugins are known for causing such issues, as they save files to run analysis on the changes, **Flow** service, when enabled, flashes files to disk to submit up-to-date files to Flow type checker, etc.

I'd also suggest to check if you have any file watchers set up in ***Preferences | Tools | File Watchers*** - those watchers that have **Auto-save edited files to trigger the watcher** enabled can cause auto-saving of the files included in watcher scope